next-auth error: id_token detected in the response, you must use client.callback() instead of client.oauthCallback()'
I am using next.js 14.2.3 and next-auth 4.24.7
Trying to create a Discord authentication, but facing OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR currently. With the follow code, it returns errror
message: 'id_token detected in the response, you must use client.callback() instead of client.oauthCallback()'.

If I add idToken: true, then it returns   message: 'unexpected iss value, expected undefined, got: https://discord.com'
How should I solve this problem?
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

export const AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      // idToken: true,
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: "URL FROM DISCORD DEVELOPER CENTER"
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(AuthOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

